# how do you configure unix ODBC on a Linux server

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have downloaded, build and configured

```
unixODBC-2.3.2.tar
```

I installed:

```
oracle-instantclient12.1-odbc-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I configured /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini as follows:

```
[Oracle]
Description = Oracle ODBC Connection
Driver = /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1
Setup =
FileUsage =
```

libsqora.so.12.1 file exists:

```
file /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

I also configured the odbc.ini file:

```
[prd_db]
Driver=Oracle
Description=prod database
Trace=Yes
ServerName=//prddb01:1521/dbp01_svc1
```

When I use prd_db credentilas to connect using isql:

isql prd_db

I get connection error. User name and password are accurate and I can connect using sql developer.

what am I missing? I need to configure odbc connection in a linux server.

```
ldd /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd918b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6c73bb2000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6c73939000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6c7371b000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f6c73503000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6c732fa000)
        libclntsh.so.12.1 => not found
        libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f6c730e8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6c72d6c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6c74242000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f6c72b61000)
```

Comment: try to use strace/ltrace to see what is happening. ODBC driver is not standalone library. It also depends on libclntsh.so (use ldd).

Comment: @ibre5041, not sure how to use that.

Comment: @ibre5041 looks like I have that library, I've updated the post. Still cannot connect

Comment: you should set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point inthe the directore where libclntsh.so.12.1 is located (the "not found" is not good)